# How is this a level set? Is it a typo?

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm reading a proof and it says that if $\phi$ is a continuous linear functional on $L^p[0,1]$ to consider the "level set" $\{f\in L^p[0,1] : \phi(f)\in (-1,1)\}$. I don't get it.

Shouldn't a level set have the form of $\{f :  \phi(f)= \text{ some fixed constant}\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily. In optimization, for example, you can define level sets of $\phi$ as the set of all $x\in$ Domain s.t $\phi(x)\leq c$, which seems to be what is going on here, with $-1<\phi(x)< 1$